Java Socket speed decreases after first echo from server
I understand that I should keep a socket open if I am planning to send multiple messages to an echo server. However, after the first message is sent, the read/write between client/server takes on average 80ms. If I open and close the socket for every single message, read/write between client/server takes on average 0ms
I couldn't identify why this is happening in the application below
public class StackOverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8080);
                    Socket socket = server.accept();
                    while (true) {
                        byte data[] = read(socket);
                        write(socket, data);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                    }
            }.start();
        
        InetSocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8080);
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        socket.connect(sockaddr, 60000);
        
        byte data[] = new byte[100];
        new Random().nextBytes(data);
        while (true) {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            write(socket, data);
            read(socket);
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.printf("Time: %d\n", end - start);
        }
    }
    
    public static void write(Socket socket, byte data[]) throws IOException {
        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Integer.BYTES);
        buffer.putInt(data.length);
        out.write(buffer.array());
        out.write(data);
        out.flush();
    }
    
    public static byte[] read(Socket socket) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
        byte head[] = new byte[Integer.BYTES];
        in.read(head);
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(head);
        int dataSize = buffer.getInt();
        byte data[] = new byte[dataSize];
        in.read(data);      
        return data;
    }
}


The output of this application is:
Time: 0
Time: 96
Time: 88
Time: 87
Time: 88
Time: 88
Time: 91
Time: 92
Time: 92
Time: 87
Time: 91
...

If I open and close the socket for each message (as shown below) I get 0ms on average.
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8080);
                    while (true) {
                        Socket socket = server.accept();
                        byte data[] = read(socket);
                        write(socket, data);
                        socket.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                
            }
        }.start();
        
        InetSocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8080);
        
        byte data[] = new byte[100];
        new Random().nextBytes(data);
        while (true) {
            Socket socket = new Socket();
            socket.connect(sockaddr, 60000);
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            write(socket, data);
            read(socket);
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.printf("Time: %d\n", end - start);
            socket.close();
        }
    }

This is the output
Time: 0
Time: 0
Time: 0
Time: 0
Time: 0
Time: 0
Time: 0
Time: 0
Time: 0
Time: 0
Time: 0
Time: 0
Time: 0
Time: 0
Time: 0
Time: 0
Time: 0
...


You're not checking the result of in.read(data);. You might not be getting any data back and/or only partial data. TCP is a stream protocol, not a message protocol. And InputStream.read doesn't necessarily have to return all the data the server has sent.  So your timings getting printed out don't represent the amount of time to receive a full message - just the amount of time to receive some data - which could include responses from previous request messages your main loop sent.

All true but timing. Write a perfect code in a question would make the code complex to understand. The problem was that I didn't set socket.setTcpNoDelay(true) and this was delaying small packets to be delivered. Thank you for your answer I really appreciate you taking time to answer my question.

Cool. You still need to check the return value from your read result to validate you got as many bytes as you think you do.

Well, very simple answer for my problem. I just need to set socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);

You could also see if flush after writing helps. In general, the operating system is trying to balance latency with network efficiency, and it isn't good at knowing that you want the data sent right now, hence why the delay is on by default.
